# Let $I$ be an ideal of a commutative ring $R$. Let $1\in I$. Prove $I=R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $I$ be an ideal of a commutative ring $R$. Let $1\in I$. Prove $I=R$.

I think if $1\in I$, then the ring $R$ has unity, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Any help/hints would be extremely helpful. ^_^

Comment: Hint: What is the definition of an ideal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the definition of an ideal,

$$RI \subseteq I$$

In particular,

$$I \subseteq R = R1 \subseteq RI \subseteq I$$

Answer (score 2):

One of the ideal properties is that $RI\subseteq I$.  With $1\in I$, then $R=R1\subseteq RI\subseteq I$.